# How to Get $.ajax() request parameter at success callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want get ajax data parameter at success callback function

like bellow

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'example.com/something',
     method: 'GET',
     data: { 'sample':'test' }, // => I want this data in success function.
     success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          // want get data parameter
          // {'sample':'test'}

          // someone answered that could get below code but I couldn't get it 
          // console.log(this.data);  => X 
     }
});
```

Comment: What you want exactly? Its not clear what you want still.

Comment: remove `this` and do `console.log(data)`

Comment: oh! I'm really sorry about confused question. I fix my question.

Comment: The AJAX generally returns JSON object you need to parse that data something like this "var obj = JSON.parse(text);"

Comment: You are trying to get value passed at `data` setting at `success`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     // want get data parameter
>     // {'sample':'test'}
> ```

Pass `data` as a property to `jqxhr` object at `beforeSend`, get object at `success`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'example.com/something',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    "sample": "test"
  },
  beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) {
    jqxhr._data = settings.url.split("?").pop();
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // want get data parameter
    // {'sample':'test'}
    var _data = jqXHR._data.split("&").slice(0, 1).pop().split("=");
    var obj = {}; obj[_data[0]] = _data[1];
    console.log(_data, obj);
    // var obj = {}; 
    // someone answered that could get below code but I couldn't get it 
    // console.log(this.data);  => X 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Should just be able to type `data.sample` in the success handler to get the value.  Alternately, you could do `data['sample']`, but that syntax really exists more for allowing you to store property names in variables for retrieving data from objects.

Answer (score 1):

Change `method` to `type` and `console.log(data)` to view the content of `data` passed to the callback function.

Also, add `dataType: 'json'` in the call.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'example.com/something',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: { 'sample':'test' },
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
          console.log(data);  // will display the content of data 
     },
     error: function(a,b,c) {
          console.log('something went wrong:',a,b,c);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.data`, in your case, to access the value "test", you'd need to use `data.sample`.

Try looking into JSON objects, as that is **generally** what AJAX requests will be returning. You're going to using "dot notation" a lot in JS.

Answer (score 0):

What's your backend code? java c# php? if c# and mvc controller,you can defination an action the pramater in the action will be you ajax pass

Comment: using python3 Django 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, you can put data into variable directly :

```
var dataObj = { 
  sample:'test' 
}; // => I want this data in success function.

$.ajax({
 url: 'example.com/something',
 method: 'GET',
 data: dataObj,
 success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      // then just console.log(dataObj.sample)
 }
});
```